# Simulate sum of correlated and uncorrelated variables with uncertainty

Tags: simulation

This is surely a simple question for many. Suppose a sum *S* of linked variables must be simulated:

- *x*: independent variable sampled from empirical pdf.
- *a* = *f1*(*x*); *f1* is a function with uncertainty bounds, and so, *a* is also sampled.
- *b* = *f2(a)*; *f2* is a function with uncertainty bounds, and so, *b* is also sampled.

*S = a + b + c ...*

Suppose that a, b, c each are sampled with 1000 realizations (list of 1 x 1000).

```
for i <- 1 to 1000
a
for j <- 1 to 1000
b
for k <- 1 to 1000
c

S < - a + b + c
```

If the sum is organized this way, as a "nested" sampling scheme, the size of *S* grows quickly at 1000^n. This is the least efficient way to do it. Which better way of sampling workflow could be implemented?

This is a general question

Comment: What is a "function with uncertainty bounds"?

Comment: it's an empirical function, a cloud of points, relating two variables

Comment: Why not do a single loop? `for i<- 1 to 1000; a,b,c = sampler(); S(i) = a+b+c`. I don't see a reason why one must compute the value of $S$ for every possible combination of samples of $a$, $b$, and $c$ instead of just computing $N$ samples of $S$ directly.